# Access variable modified in function in render method

Tags: javascript, reactjs, modal-dialog, react-modal

I have the following code (trimmed the form and some other boilerplate):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Modal from 'react-modal';

var responseMessages;
export default class ContactForm extends Component {

handleSubmit(event) {
    responseMessages = []

    fetch('http://127.0.0.1:4000/test', {
        method: 'POST',
        mode: 'cors',
        headers: {
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin":"*",
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
        body: JSON.stringify(data)
    }).then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseJson) => {
        for(var i = 0; i < responseJson.errors.length; i++) {
            responseMessages.push(
                <p>{responseJson.errors[i].msg}</p>
            );
        }
    })
    .then(this.openModal());
}

render() {
  return (
    <div>
    <Modal  isOpen={this.state.modalIsOpen}
            onRequestClose={this.closeModal}
            ariaHideApp={false}
            style={customStyles}>
            <div>
                {responseMessages}
            </div>
   </Modal>
   </div>
)}}
```

Adding `{responseMessages}` in the Modal displays nothing, but if I change it to `{console.log(responseMessages)}` it shows in the console that `responseMessages` is not empty (it has different length, but not empty)
What could be the reason for that?

EDIT: openModal function:

```
openModal() {
    this.setState({modalIsOpen: true});
}
```

ResponseJson:

```
{"errors":[{"location":"body","param":"message","msg":"error message","value":"entered value"}]}
```

Comment: Can you please post your responseJson here ?

Comment: the console is invoke immediately while the response data came later

Comment: edited with asked information. @aviram83 this sounds as a good reason. Do you have ideas how to handle this case?

Comment: Better you use state(declare responseMessages  as state variable in constructor).  And then use setstate to change the state of responseMessages then your component will rerender with new data.

Comment: @MukulSharma do you know how to set state of a array while iterating over it? Ofc I could always use second variable, but I was thinking for more elegant way

Comment: try this - 
.then( this.setState({responseMessages : responseMessages });)

Comment: `this.openModal())` will be called immediately. try `.then(this.openModal.bind(this));`. or `.then(() => this.openModal());`

Comment: @Vikramaditya your comment works. Add it as an answere, I'll mark it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a javascript issue and has nothing to do with react.
when you write `.then(this.openModal())` the `openModal` function will be called immediately. So the actual code should be

`.then(this.openModal.bind(this));`

or using arrow function

`or .then(() => this.openModal());`

if you are using some autobind decorator or if you are binding functions inside constructor then simply `.then(this.openModal);` should also work.